# Reg~x for the N~number

Tags: java, string

Would be grateful your help.

What would be elegant Regx to check a String whether it holds a number ?  any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: I would use the constructor `BigDecimal(String)` and catch the `NumberFormatException` if anything goes wrong, why do you want some regexp??

Comment: Thnx for the suggestion. But exception would be costly and the programme might be required to remodel into Exception Management system

Comment: Just wrap it all up in a method, unless you're using AOP around any Exception throwing code its a non-issue

Comment: Catching an exception is just a few nanoseconds slower than parsing with a regexp. I wouldn't worry about how costly it is unless you expect many thousands of exceptions per second.

Comment: According to the [Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) there are no thousands separators allowed in a BigDecimal, nor can the decimal point be anything but the dot. Am I missing something?

Comment: The NumberFormat.parseObject would work with different locales, but i do not know if it throws internally.

Comment: What is an exception management system ?

Comment: this is a completely premature optimization and will complicate your program way more than simply creating the object and catching the parse exception, a wise person once said **"if you have a problem and solve it with a regular expression, now you have TWO problems!"**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that an exception (even if it is triggered) is that much more expensive than a regular expression - you'd have to profile it and see if it really makes a difference.

That said, a regular expression that implements the BigDecimal grammar according to the [Java Docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) is

```
[+-]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

Explanation:

```
[+-]?       # optional sign
(?:         # required significand: either...
 \d+        # a number
 (?:\.\d*)? # optionally followed by a dot, optionally followed by more digits
 |          # or...
 \.\d+      # just a dot, followed by digits (in this case required)
)           # end of significand
(?:         # optional exponent
 [eE]       # required exponent indicator
 [+-]?      # optional sign
 \d+        # required digits
)?          # end of exponent
```

If you want to allow different number formats (and thousands separators) you could first get those values from [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) and build your regex with it.

Something like this (I don't know Java, so feel free to correct my Syntax Errors):

```
// you need java.util.regex.Pattern and java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols
string ds = Pattern.quote(DecimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator())
string gs = Pattern.quote(DecimalFormatSymbols.getGroupingSeparator())
string ms = Pattern.quote(DecimalFormatSymbols.getMinusSign())
string es = Pattern.quote(DecimalFormatSymbols.getExponentSeparator())

string myre = 
    "(?xi)\n       # verbose, case-insensitive regex" +
    "[+" +ms+ "]?  # optional sign\n" +
    "(?:           # required significand: either...\n" +
    " (?:\\d{1,3}(?:" +gs+ "\\d{3}|\\d++) # a number with optional thousand separators,\n" +
    " (?:" +ds+ "\\d*)? # optionally followed by a dot, optionally followed by more digits\n" +
    " |            # or...\n" +
      ds+ "\\d+    # just a dot, followed by digits (in this case required)\n" +
    ")             # end of significand\n" +
    "(?:           # optional exponent\n" +
      es+ "        # required exponent indicator\n" +
    " [+" +ms+ "]? # optional sign\n" +
    " \\d+         # required digits\n" +
    ")?            # end of exponent"

boolean foundMatch = subjectString.matches(myregex);
```

You could then replace the locale-dependent bits back into their US counterparts before handing the number over for BigDecimal conversion, if that's not locale-aware.

Comment: The first regex only works for numbers that conform to the specs for BigDecimal as laid out in the Java docs linked above. The code sample (where you have to get your thousands separators, decimal separators etc. first) should also work with numbers like 1,000,000.00.

Comment: was referring to the 2nd one Tim. even Zero is considered as invalid

Comment: You do know that you need to escape backslashes in Java strings, don't you? The second regex is identical to the first one (just in verbose form); the third regex (inside the Java code snippet) is the only one that will match numbers that do not conform to the BigDecimal specification, but it needs to be built dynamically for this to work. Have you tried that one?

Comment: thanks. I knw the escape scene. thers some loopholes there anway I have written one similar to urs using regx guide.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the implementation of the Apache's [NumberUtils.isNumber](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=ru#RDk_icqX2EA/tags/LANG_2_3_RC3/src/java/org/apache/commons/lang/math/NumberUtils.java&q=NumberUtils%20apache%20commons&l=1366). I wouldn't recommend using regular expressions for such validation.

Comment: Is number just checks if all characters in the string are digits. Even the empty string `isNumber`.

Comment: isDigits does it. isNumber is much more sophisticated. isNumber checks whether some string can be parsed as number.

Answer (score 2):

Do not use regular expressions, they almost always are not the answer to any problem. You might accept some regex and then later on find out that it does not cover all situations. If you really want to know if a string has a BigDecimal, why not ask the source BigDecimal itself, after all it by definition is always right while using a regular expression cant always be right, you might just get it wrong.